# How do RunAs without setting admin mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, runas

I would like to be able to use RunAs in Windows 7 without using an admin account, or using an account that happens to be an admin without bypassing UAC.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Clarification: Are you wanting to do a `Run As:` as a different user who happens to be an administrator, but you want that program run under lowered privileges, not as a admin?

Answer (score 2):

Either your question is missing something or you're misunderstanding `runas`:

`Runas /user:machine\userwhoisnotanadmin [command]`

You can use `runas` both as a non-admin, and to run as a non-admin account.

Comment: Just a note: the `RunAs` command will NEVER elevate a non elevated context to a elevated context, so if the OP wants what I asked about in my comment in the original question `runas` is exactly what you want to use.